# SQL Query Help: update table values with data from two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I ran a voting contest where WordPress users voted for bartenders (WordPress posts).

The voting plugin I used created a votes table ('wordpress_votes') that includes 1 row for each vote.  Each row contains both the user ID ('user_id') and bartender ID ('post_id').

OBJECTIVE: I'm trying to create an result that provides the email addresses for users based on the address of the bartender.

1. Email addresses can be found in the table wordpress_users, which has rows that include both 'user_id' and 'user_email'
2. Bartender addresses can be found in a table called wordpress_postmeta, which includes rows with the  address as a custom field 'employer_address' in rows that also include 'post_id'

Can anyone suggest the proper MSSQL query that can pull the results from these three tables?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result

```
select wv.user_id,wu.user_email,wv.post_id,wp.employer_address from wordpress_votes wv 
inner join wordpress_users wu on wu.user_id=wv.user_id
inner join wordpress_postmeta wp on wp.post_id=wv.post_id
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this one.  Note that _employer_address_ is not a column within the _wordpress_votes_ table.  It's actually a _meta_key_, and I'm looking for the _meta_value_ associated with this for a specific _post_type_ (bartender).  Also - since I'm new to SQL, is the above syntax shorthand, so I have to add `[]` and use full table names?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  u.user_email,
  pm.employer_address
from wordpress_votes v
join wordpress_users u on u.user_id = v.user_id
join wordpress_postmeta pm on pm.post_id = v.post_id
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Hey Rob, thank you!  Clarification though, the employer_address is not a column head, it's actually a name-value pair (meta_key, meta_value) within the postmeta table.  Can you revise the syntax above with this in consideration.  I tried the following but it did not work:
    SELECT u.user_email, post_id, meta_value
FROM wordpress_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'employer_address'
from wordpress_wti_like_post v
join wordpress_users u on u.user_id = v.user_id
join wordpress_postmeta pm on pm.post_id = v.post_id